# How to run Roller Coaster Tycoon 2 in a window with PlayOnLinux and Wine?

Tags: ubuntu, wine, rollercoaster-tycoon-2

Following the instructions from the /r/rct subreddit, I was able to install RCT 2 inside Ubuntu using PlayOnLinux. The only problem is, the game glitches when running in full screen, such as things becoming misaligned, etc.

Using PlayOnLinux's settings, how can I run the game in a window with Wine?

Answer (score 2):

Inside PlayOnLinux, go to the "Configure" screen for the RCT2 installation, then go to the "Wine" tab then click "Configure Wine." Once the configuration window loads, click on the "Graphics" tab and click "Emulate a Virtual Desktop."

You can also download the hack that allows RCT2 to be run natively in a window, but this is a far easier solution for Linux.

Comment: Note that this is psuedo-windowed mode: the application thinks it's running full-screen when it's actually in a window.  Because of this, it may not fix all full-screen glitches.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a version of RollerCoaster Tycoon 2 that runs natively on Linux, try [OpenRCT2](https://openrct2.org).

> OpenRCT2 is an open-source re-implementation of RollerCoaster Tycoon 2 (RCT2), expanding the game with new features, fixing bugs and raising game limits.
>   <sub>- [openrct2.org](https://openrct2.org)</sub>

One of these new features is support for fullscreen, windowed, and borderless windowed mode.

OpenRCT2 is available for Windows, Mac, and Linux. Do note that OpenRCT2 requires that you own a copy of RollerCoaster Tycoon 2 to run.

---

*Disclaimer: I have contributed [tooltip descriptions](https://github.com/OpenRCT2/OpenRCT2/pull/3394) for OpenRCT2 on GitHub.*